# Восстановление пароля

Tags: php, пароль, mysql

**Организовать на PHP восстановление пароля.**

*В БД пароль хранится в виде двойного md5 хеша.*

Надо: выслать человеку письмо с ссылкой для активации. 
**Не знаю**, как генерировать адрес для активации и после отправки письма, проверить активирована ли ссылка.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пароли либо сбрасывают вместо восстановления, либо хранят в таблице, которая не принимает участия в других действиях сайта, лучше - в другой БД. Первое безопаснее.

Генерация ссылки - банально. Новое поле в таблице, hash. Если не пустое - юзер заблокирован. Т.е. на кнопку "восстановить" жмем - пишем в поле какой-то рандом(`aa123addss231`), отсылаем письмо с ним же (`?hash=aa123addss231`).

```
if (!empty($_GET['hash']) && !empty($_POST['new_passwd'])) {
  // ищем ИД по хэшу, если есть - трем хэш и вписываем на место пароля md5(md5($_POST['new_passwd']))
  }
```

Comment: для пущей безопастности стоит еще и посолить ;) `md5(md5($_POST['new_passwd']).SALT)`

Comment: Sh4dow говорит правильно, но лучше пользователю возвращать явные сообщения об ошибках, а не простую надпись в духе: "У вас есть ошибки". В идеале - сделать класс для локализации. И пароли хешировать не md5, а функцией crypt, и соль генерировать 8-ми битную. Желаю хорошего кода.

Answer (score 1):

Вот в принципе простой алгоритм для понимания-->

```
$abc= array("Ваш словарь, символы"); 
        for($i=0; $i<50; $i++){
            $code[$i]=$abc[mt_rand(0,Длина словаря)];
            $code_submit.= $string.$code[$i];       
        }
    $_POST['code']=$code_submit;

// После этого идет INSERT в базу при регистрации пользователя, с этим кодом!
```

Теперь у нас есть   письмо с адресом  www.*****/conferm/$code_submit , если пользователь заходит по урлу, мы парсим наш урл и проверяем если ли такой код в базе!

Comment: `sha1(rand(1, 1000000))` не?)